# How To Get The Unique Elements for Each Level (Like MainMenu/Submenu1/SubMenu2) On Json using java or javascript...?

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have the json Like below, i want to get the unique child sub nodes for each main nodes

```
{
    "name": "MENUS",
    "value": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "MENU1",
            "value": {},
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "SubMenu1",
                    "value": {},
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "SubMenu2",
                            "value": {},
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "SubMenu3",
                                    "value": {
                                        "Pld": "1"
                                    },
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "MENU1",
            "value": {},
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "SubMenu1",
                    "value": {},
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "SubMenu2",
                            "value": {},
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "SubMenu4",
                                    "value": {
                                        "Pld": "1"
                                    },
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I wanted the JSON like below format for each main nodes i want unique sub nodes means the subnode should not be a duplicate in the JSON.

```
{
    "name": "MENUS",
    "value": "",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "MENU1",
            "value": {},
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "SubMenu1",
                    "value": {},
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "SubMenu2",
                            "value": {},
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "SubMenu3",
                                    "value": {
                                        "Pld": "1"
                                    },
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "SubMenu4",
                                    "value": {
                                        "Pld": "1"
                                    },
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Could you please anyone help me how to get the unique hierarchical tree JSON.

EDIT::Adding POJO classes for reference

This is how my java pojo looks like,

### MenuTree.java

private String name;
private String value;
private Children[] children;

### Children.java

private String name;
private Value value;
private Children[] children;

### Value.java

private String Pld;

Comment: java or javascript? :)

Comment: [json](http://json.org/) or not is the question.

Comment: what happens, if the second part contains deeper nested items then the first? should it mapped to a single nested part? btw, what have you tried?

Comment: Please share what have you tried.

Comment: i'm stuck how to proceed further

Comment: java javascript both are fine

Comment: if the second part contains netsed items then it shud append to the last child like below,                                                                      {"name":"MENUS","value":"","children":[{"name":"MENU1","value":{},"children":[{"name":"SubMenu1","value":{},"children":[{"name":"SubMenu2","value":{},"children":[{"name":"SubMenu3","value":{"Pld":"1"},"children":[]},{"name":"SubMenu4","value":{"Pld":"1"},"children":[{"name":"SubMenu5","value":{"Pld":"1"},"children":[]}]}]}]}]}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach by searching eachlevel for existing name and append the array with new objects if not found.

```js
var object = { name: "MENUS", value: "", children: [{ name: "MENU1", value: {}, children: [{ name: "SubMenu1", value: {}, children: [{ name: "SubMenu2", value: {}, children: [{ name: "SubMenu3", value: { Pld: "1" }, children: [] }] }] }] }, { name: "MENU1", value: {}, children: [{ name: "SubMenu1", value: {}, children: [{ name: "SubMenu2", value: {}, children: [{ name: "SubMenu4", value: { Pld: "1" }, children: [] }] }] }] }] },
    unique = [object].reduce(function iter(r, { name, value, children = [] }) {
        var object = r.find(o => o.name === name);
        if (!object) {
            object = { name, value };
            r.push(object);
        }
        children.reduce(iter, object.children = object.children || []);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```